# AWS SNS Topic - Change Email Sender Id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have an AWS SNS topic that publishes emails to user endpoints.

The sender of the email is no-reply@aws...etc

I have a verified SES email for my company that I would like to apply to the sender of the SNS topic.

I added the SourceARN to the SNS Topic's access policy like the documentation said

[Doc to AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/configure-sns-notifications.html)

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "SNS:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:region:myaccid:test-std-topic",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "myaccid",
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:region:myaccid:identity/no-reply@stackexample.com"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But after applying and publishing another message, the sender is still no-reply@aws... Instead of the verified identity that I have linked via SourceArn.

How do I modify the SNS Topic's access policy to apply this verified identity?

Comment: I don't think SNS supports this; `AWS:SourceArn` doesn't do what you think. You probably want S**E**S for more control over emails.

Comment: I've seen alot of documentation for changing the SMS sender id, figured there was a similiar thing for email but just couldnt find it. Never hurts to ask. Thanks for the info @ceejayoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change this configuration.
SNS controls the sender identity (e-mail address) that is used to send e-mail messages through an SNS topic.

The access policy and documentation you mentioned refers to a different use case. It refers to SES feedback forwarding mechanism to track bounce/complaint/delivery events. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-sending-activity-using-notifications-sns.html)

You can read more about aws:SourceArn condition [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-sourcearn).

If you want to change the sender identity for your emails, you'd have to use [SES APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email.html)